# made from or made of \ question

Tags: grammar

I noticed on one page of grammar an exercise with solution and I wonder how the answer is MADE FROM

**Fewer and fewer bottles are made from glass these days.**

The question has two choices to fill in ( made from \ made with )

**I see neither made from nor made with is right.**

I think it should be ( made of ) because we talk about material and the glass is always obvious on the bottles, so how is it made from ?

It is perhaps in error printed
https://www.tolearnenglish.com/exercises/exercise-english-2/exercise-english-117032.php

And here it is from one grammar book:
[image]

Comment: When talking about what material is used to manufacture something: made of/made from/made with are often used interchangeably. There are slight differences in nuance, but most people don't worry too much about that in every day speech. For example: Bread is made of/made from/made with flour.

Answer (score 1):

"Made from" indicates the primary material in something, like the glass of a glass bottle.

"Made with" indicates either a material something includes --not necessarily the primary material-- or a tool or method used to make it. It's mostly used to give the ingredients in food or drink.

Since glass bottles are made entirely out of glass, "made from" is better. "Made with" would indicate that glass is somehow used in manufacturing, but doesn't mean the result is a glass bottle.

Comment: You could also address "made of" as an option

Comment: But I noticed in many books  as bottles are made of glass    I see made from is not correct because you can see the material of glass is obvious on bottles ...  If the material prosperity physical or chemical  is changed then it is made from    For example Glass is made from sand  ( you can't see any trail of sand on glass )   Shoes are made of leather  ( leather is not changed )  and it is applicable to bottles = the same

Comment: 2-  I am sure , made with is not the solution  (Neither  made form nor made with is correct )

Comment: Ahmad, we can use both _made of_ and _made from_ in all cases. It's true that _made from_ puts more emphasis on the idea that ingredients have been changed in the process, but it isn't _only_ used in these cases.